# Data Validation with "Select" Menu

Tags: javascript, html

A part of the application I am creating asks the user to enter the state of their current residence, it then asks the user to enter their postcode. The program then tests to see if the postcode is valid for that State.

Eg. State entered "VIC" postcode can't be >=4000 or < 3000

Instead of either receiving the error message or not, I constantly receive the error message even when the postcode is valid

JS for my WebPage

```
function validate () {
var result = true
var errMsg = " "
var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
var other = document.getElementById("text").value;


    if (state == "VIC" || postcode >= 4000 || postcode < 3000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "VIC" || postcode >=9000 || postcode < 8000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "NSW" || postcode >=3000 || postcode < 1000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "QLD" || postcode <4000 || postcode >= 5000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen stae\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "QLD" || postcode <9000 || postcode >= 10000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "NT" || postcode >= 1000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "WA" || postcode < 6000 || postcode >= 7000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "SA" || postcode < 5000 || postcode >= 6000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "TAS" || postcode < 7000 || postcode >= 8000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }
    else if (state == "ACT" || postcode >= 1000) {
            errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n"
            result = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("other").checked = true || other == "If you selected Other, enter your answer here...") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "You have selected other, please enter your answer into the text box provided"
        result = false;
    }
    if (errMsg != "") {
            document.getElementById("errMessage").value = errMsg;

    }
    return result;
}

function init() {
    if (document.getElementById("applypage")!=null) {
    var regForm = document.getElementById("regform");
    job_apply();
    regForm.onsubmit = validate;

    }
    else if (document.getElementById("jobspage") !=null) {
    storeJobNumber();
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

HTML for my webPage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="CWA HELP DESK" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CWA, Help, Desk" />
    <meta name="author" content ="Harry Keys" />
    <title>Application Form</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="apply.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="applypage">

<form id="regform" method="post" action="http://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" novalidate="novalidate">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Company Logo" />
    <h1> Job Application Form </h1>

<fieldset>
    <p><label for="jobNumber">Job Reference Number</label>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" name="jobNumber" id="jobNumber" maxlength="5" size="7" required="required" readonly/>
    </p>
    <p><label for="givenName">Given Name</label>
        <input type="text"  onkeypress="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)" name="givenName" id="givenName" maxlength="20" size="15" required="required"/>
      <label for="familyName">Family Name</label>
        <input type="text"  onkeypress="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)" name="familyName" id="familyName" maxlength="20" size="15" required="required"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>
    <p><label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" required="required"/>
    </p>
    <p><label for="staddress">Street Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="staddress" id="staddress" maxlength="40" required="required"/>
        <label for="suburb">Suburb/Town</label>
        <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" maxlength="40" required="required"/>
    </p>
    <p><label for="state">State</label>
        <select name="state" id="state">
            <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
            <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
            <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
            <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
            <option value="NT">NT</option>
            <option value="WA">WA</option>
            <option value="SA">SA</option>
            <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
            <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p><label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" maxlength="4" size="4" required="required"/>
    </p>
    <p><label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required"/>
    </p>
    <p><label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" maxlength="12" size="12" required="required"/>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Gender</legend>
    <p> <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="Gender" value="male" required="required"/>
        <label for="female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="Gender" value="female"/>
        <label for="other">Other</label>
        <input type="radio" id="undefined" name="Gender" value="undefined"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Skills List</legend>
    <p> <label for="teamwork">Teamwork</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="teamwork" name="Skill[]" value="Teamwork" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="rubyskills">Ruby Experience</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rubyskills" name="Skill[]" value="Rubyskills"/>
        <label for="efficiency">Efficiency</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="efficiency" name="Skill[]" value="Efficiency"/>
        <label for="communication">Communication</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="communication" name="Skill[]" value="Communication"/>
        <label for="other">Other</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="Skill[]" value="other"/>
    </p>
    <p> <textarea id="text" name="Skill[]" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="If you selected Other, enter your answer here..."></textarea>
    </p>
</fieldset>
</fieldset>
<p> <textarea id="errMessage" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea> </p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset Form"/>
</form>
```

When I select "NSW" and enter a postcode that is not >=3000 or <1000 I should not receive an error. But I still do

Comment: You're sure that is correct? `Eg. State entered "VIC" postcode must be >=4000 or < 3000` That would mean it has to be greater or equal 4000 OR smaller than 3000. That doesn't really make sense. I think you mean it should be between 3000 and 4000 ?

Comment: Yeah I do mean that I have just changed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your if-else-if construct is a little bit confusing.
I'd recommend a switch-block to validate which state has been chosen and with each case check if the postcode is in the correct range.

Something like:

```
function validate() {
  var result = true
  var errMsg = " "
  var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var other = document.getElementById("text").value;
  switch (state) {
    case "VIC":
      if (postcode >= 3000 && postcode < 4000) {
        result = true;
      }
      break;
    case "NSW":
      if (postcode >= 1000 && postcode < 3000) {
        result = true;
      }
      break;
    case "QLD":
      if (postcode >= 4000 && postcode < 5000) {
        result = true;
      }
      break;
  }
  if (!result) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "You have entered an invalid postcode for your chosen state\n";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("other").checked = true || other == "If you selected Other, enter your answer here...") {
    errMsg = "You have selected other, please enter your answer into the text box provided"
    result = false;
  }

  if (errMsg != "") {
    document.getElementById("errMessage").value = errMsg;

  }
  return result;
}
```